# Numpy Select with Multiple Conditions Not Returning Values

Tags: python, numpy, select, conditional-statements

I combined three dataframes that have multiple `email` columns, then renamed the columns for ease of scripting. I'm trying to create a master email column based on conditions. If `C` is populated, use `C`. If not, and `B` is populated, use `B`. If not, and `A` is populated, use `A`. For some reason it's only filling in the master column if `C` is populated. Even if `A` is populated, it's returning a null value.

```
dfs = [df_A, d365, df_C]
from functools import reduce
dfFinal = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='leadId'), dfs)

import numpy as np
emailconditions = [
dfFinal['EmailC'] is not None,
(dfFinal['EmailC'] is None) & (dfFinal['EmailB'] is not None),
(dfFinal['EmailC'] is None) & (dfFinal['EmailB'] is None)]

emailvalues = [
dfFinal['EmailC'],
dfFinal['EmailB'],
dfFinal['EmailA']]

dfFinal['emailFinal'] = np.select(emailconditions, emailvalues)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataframe and your expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting `emailconditions` like so:

```
emailconditions = [
dfFinal['EmailC'].notna(),
dfFinal['EmailC'].isna() & dfFinal['EmailB'].notna(),
dfFinal['EmailC'].isna() & dfFinal['EmailB'].isna()]
```

Key point is to use `notna()` instead of `is not None` and `isna()` instead of `is None`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution, which grabs the first truthy value out of the columns in whichever priority order you want:

```py
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
      a     b     c
0     x     w  None
1  None     y  None
2     k  None     z

In [4]: order = ("c", "b", "a")

In [5]: df.apply(lambda row: next(row[col] for col in order if row[col]), axis=1)
Out[5]:
0    w
1    y
2    z
dtype: object
```

If you anticipate having rows where *none* of the columns have a value, then you'd probably want something like this:

```py
def first_truthy(row, order):
    try:
        return next(row[col] for col in order if row[col])
    except StopIteration:
        return None
```

Output:

```py
In [7]: df
Out[7]:
      a     b     c
0     x     w  None
1  None     y  None
2     k  None     z
3  None  None  None


In [8]: df.apply(lambda row: first_truthy(row, order), axis=1)
Out[8]:
0       w
1       y
2       z
3    None
dtype: object
```

Not that this is likely slower than boolean masking, but (in my opinion) easier to reason about and debug, and doesn't require the extra dependency on `numpy`. If you need performance, @richardec's solution is likely vastly superior, though I have not benchmarked our solutions.